# `Field "User" is already defined on model "User".` while saving my schema.prisma file is an issue

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

In my `schema.prisma` file, I  set up the `User` model so that a `User` can be a member of one or many teams, and can be added as a member by one or multiple users, here's a copy of my schema to achieve this, but upon saving the file, I continue to get several of these `User User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])` relations populate the file with error `Field "User" is already defined on model "User".` even after removing them and trying to save again. How do I resolve this issue?

`model User`:

```
model User {
  id                     String              @id @default(cuid())
  userId                 String?             @unique
  firstName          String?
  profileImage       String?
  password           String?
  image              String?
  lastName           String?
  invitedById        String?
      // ... other fields
  
     // Teams and Invites
  Teams        Team[] @relation("TeamMembers", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  CreatedTeams Team[] @relation("TeamCreator", fields: [id], references: [userId])
  InvitedBy    User[] @relation("UserInviter", fields: [invitedById], references: [id])
  Invites      User[] @relation("UserInvitee", fields: [id], references: [invitedById])
  
    // InvitedByUser and InviterUser
  InvitedByUser User @relation("InvitedByUser", fields: [invitedById], references: [id])
  InviterUser   User @relation("InviterUser", fields: [id], references: [invitedById])
  
   // Other relations
  UserRelationWith       User?  @relation("UserRelationWith", fields: [userId], 
  references: [id])
  UserRelationTwo        User[] @relation("UserRelationTwo", fields: [userId], 
  references: [id])
  UserArray              User[] @relation("UserArray", fields: [userId], references: 
  [id])


// Below `User` relations instances that continues to self-populate upon saving the file with error: `'Field "User" is already defined on model "User".'` This is preventing the file from being saved/migrated.


 User                   User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  User                   User[]
  User                   User[]
  User                   User?
  User                   User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  User                   User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  User                   User?
  User                   User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  User                   User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  User                   User?
  User                   User?
  User                   User?
}
```

`//model Team`:

```
model Team {
  id         String      @unique @default(uuid())
  email      String      @unique
  name       String?
  firstName  String?
  lastName   String?
  isVerified Boolean?
  image      String?
  members    User[]      @relation("TeamMembers", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  createdBy  User        @relation("TeamCreator", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     String?
  createdAt  DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime    @updatedAt
  teamId     String?
  User       User?       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

Relevant image: [image]

Any help to fixing this issue will be very much appreciated. Thanks